# RegEx match multiple string conditions in AND operator

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, logical-operators

I need to match the following rules in long string:

```
 - key1=.*(a1|a2).* OR key2=.*(b1|b2|b3).* OR key3=.*(c1|c2|c3).*
 - AND key1=.*(d1|d2|d3|d4).*
```

the **'='** is intended as **'contains any of'**

I've tried the following regex on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), but is not working as expected:

`.*((key1=(?=.*(a1|a2)))|(key2=(?=.*(b1|b2|b3)))|(key3=(?=.*(c1|c2|c3))))&(key1=(?=.*(d1|d2|d3|d4))).*`

some string that should match:

```
key1=a2,d3
key2=b1,b3key1=d1
key2=b2key3=c3,a2key1=d4
key1=d2abckey2=b2,b3key1=a1
```

some string that should NOT match:

```
key1=d2
key1=a1key2=b1
key2=b2key3=a1
```

what is wrong with my regex expression? what do you think?
many thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single positive lookahead to make sure that key1 is present with at least an occurrence of `d` and a digit 1-4.

Then you can use another lookahead to assert one of key 1, key2 or key3 with the allowed digits.

Note that you can shorten the alternations `|` for `(a1|a2)` to a character class `a[12]`

```
^(?=.*key1=[a-z0-9,]*d[1-4])(?=.*(?:key1=a[12]|key2=b[123]|key3=c[123])).+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGcCJF/1)

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `.*key1=[a-z0-9,]*d[1-4]` Match key1= having a value of `d1` `d2` `d3` `d4` by optionally matching the allowed characters that precede it `[a-z0-9,]*`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?=.*` Positive lookahead, assert what is at the right is

  - `(?:` Non capture group to list the alternatives

    - `key1=a[12]` Match `key1=a1` or `key1=a2`
    - `|` Or
    - `key2=b[123]` Match key2 with the allowed values
    - `|` Or
    - `key3=c[123]` Match key3 with the allowed values
  - `)` Close non capture group
- `)` Close positive lookahead
- `.+` Match 1 or more characters

Comment: thank you for the answer, it actually match properly 
key1=d3,a2
but it does not mach anymore if you reverse d3 with a2
key1=a2,d3
any suggestions?

Comment: @G.Joe If you want that for all the keys, then you can optionally repeat all allowed chars first `^(?=.*key1=[a-z0-9,]*d[1-4])(?=.*(?:key1=[a-z0-9,]*a[12]|key2=[a-z0-9,]*b[123]|key3=[a-z0-9,]*c[123])).+` See https://regex101.com/r/cjLeDW/1